# After killing hung install of a Robotino package with "kill PID", now I cannot install package again

Tags: package-management, software-installation

I was installing a Robotino package from the Ubuntu Software Center, but the USCenter hung for so long so I killed the install with `kill PID`.

It was evidently a bad choice, because now I cannot recover the broken installation to install again with either USCenter or dbpk.

I already deleted the 'lock' file and executed `apt-get clean/autoclean/autoremove`, but these techniques failed.

My errors:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the download directory
```

What should I do to install the package again?

Comment: E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the download directory
=> this is the errors I got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the lock file is not a good idea, its there for a reason.

This typically means that there is still a process that holds the lock - any of synaptic, dpkg, apt-get.

What you can do is to run `ps ax | grep <insert process name>` and try to kill which show up.

Verify again if it is killed, if not use `kill -9 <proc name>`

Another easy solution is to simply restart.

Comment: thank you! it's great! after restarting my computer, it works fine again :). Whatever the case, you still have to kill the task, the installation (I did it) and result in a broken installation with(out) lock file